# Run "sw-precache" command from c#

Tags: c#, command-line, cmd, progressive-web-apps, sw-precache

I want to generate "service-worker.js" using [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache/tree/943f1e827aa03be4200789d453d3c9be4921b6cf)

from command line (cmd.exe) I run this command and output is :

**Total precache size is about 145 kB for 35 resources.
service-worker.js has been generated with the service worker contents.**

When I run this command from C# output is **empty**, here is my code:

```
Process proc = new Process
                    {
                        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                        {
                            FileName = @"cmd.exe",
                            Arguments = @"/c sw-precache",
                            UseShellExecute = false,
                            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                            RedirectStandardError = true,
                            CreateNoWindow = true,
                            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(myDir)
                        }
                    };
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

If I run command like "dir" in Arguments = @"/c dir", output contains message from dir command,

what I do wrong?

Edit:
In Console Application, output is returned normally, but not in Web Application

Comment: Why not run `sw-precache` directly?

Comment: @Vilx- I have to automate the process

Comment: what Vilx meant is setting the `FileName` to `sw-precache` and not using `cmd.exe` at all.

Comment: @Behrooz "FileName " => Gets or sets the application or document to start, it must to be a file, "sw-precache" is a command

Comment: I doubt that. There is no `sw-precache` command in cmd.exe, and AFAIK you can only add new "commands" by placing files in PATH or AppPaths. Try setting the `UseShellExecute` flag to `true` and `sw-precache` in the `FileName`.

Answer (score 0):

`WaitForExit` first then read the output. It stays after the process has exited.

Comment: Is your web application running in full trust or partial trust? I'm not a web developer so I can't be sure, but this could be it.

Comment: my web app has full control permissions, this is not the problem (